# add mobile software exe in my msi file and need to run before my msi file run on client system

Tags: c#, setup-deployment

I have made msi file of my project using setup and deployment option from visual studio.I want to add one exe file of mobile software in my setup folder and i want ,that mobile software exe should be run before my msi file from my setup folder.I don't know that how i give the path of that software exe and run from my setup folder.

I have used prerequisites option and also add file in my application folder while making setup,but i don't get any solution of my problem.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

A prerequisite is the correct solution. Visual Studio setup projects do not support custom prerequisite creation. However, it can be done by manually generating the required manifests.

You can find the manifests structure here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229223(VS.80).aspx

These manifests can be generated automatically with the [Bootstrapper Manifest Generator](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg) tool.

After generating the package manifests, you can add all these files (including the package) in a separate folder in the Visual Studio prerequisites folder, for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages
```

You can then select the prerequisite in your setup project property pages.